# Como utilizar arquivos CSS diferentes para cada view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5

Gostaria de saber, se é possível estar utilizando arquivos CSS "auxiliares".

Por exemplo, em meu projeto ASP.NET MVC 5, como é de conhecimento de todos, e default a utilização do `BootStrap`, porém teria como criar um arquivo .css separado para algumas views que venho criando?

Ou, se, necessariamente toda programação css tem que estar dentro do `BootStrap.css`

Comment: Sim tem, basta você configurar no `blunde` e inserir na `View`.

Comment: Poderia me dar um direcionamento? ou uma explicação sobre?

Comment: Lendo aqui você terá uma boa explicação. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn168847.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi da sua necessidade, você poderia criar um section e nas views que fossem preciso, apontar o css necessário.

Por exemplo, ter na sua Layout `@RenderSection("css", required: false)`. E nas views que implementam seu layout  e usar

`@section css {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/caminho/para/css" />
}`

É valido lembrar que o arquivo de Layout é um cshtml, então dependo da necessidade você pode implementar lógica simples (embora eu não ache uma boa ideia).